# Spring Boot 1.5.x - How to configure Undertow thread pools for EndpointWebMvc?

Tags: java, spring-boot, undertow

I'm using Undertow and configured thread pool sizes with `server.undertow.io-threads` and `server.undertow.worker-threads`. I'm also using a separate `management.port` for all the Actuator endpoint stuff.

Unfortunately those thread pool sizes are used for both Undertow instances and I couldn't find any Untertow properties dedicated to the management part. Providing a [custom UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.10.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-configure-undertow) doesn't work either as it's not available in the management child context.

I came up with a [rather hacky solution](https://gist.github.com/mseitner/dfe4147564d980bf5965ecdd53e1e94f) but I had to break up Undertow's class encapsulation using reflection, so it probably won't work in more restrictive environments.

Is there an idiomatic way to configure individual thread pool sizes for Undertow?